# How do I see all newest questions (even negatively voted ones) with the new navigation?

Tags: bug, new-nav

I've added the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag to this because it appears that you *can't* display these questions without using search. This is bad for several reasons:

- Spam posts disappear from the questions list but can't be deleted unless enough people catch it via the "There are X new posts..." link or a moderator comes along and cleans up after a few flags
- Meta posts disappear when many disagree. This is inappropriate. Despite the disagreement, there may be other opinions to offer. This effectively silences the opinions that everyone disagrees with
- Poor questions can be fixed and revived. If a question is never seen though, it will be ignored.

---

With the old navigation method, if I wished to watch the newest questions page of Meta, I could do so and see negatively scored questions. I can't seem to find those questions any longer.

I am using this link:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest
```

My front page looks like this:

[image: Meta Front Page]

The problem is that [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261789/upvote-downvote-bandwagon-and-how-to-stop-it) was asked two hours ago and should appear, but it has a score of -13.

How do I get those low scoring questions visible again?

Comment: Yeah, we need some sort of "unhide questions with low scores" button... or, honestly, on Meta, is it necessary to hide these questions? We all know that downvotes here don't mean the question is bad, it often simply means that people disagree with it. That's not a reason to hide it, though.

Comment: Even on non-meta it is highly important to see even very negatively voted questions *somewhere* or else there is no way to find them at all and they could as well be deleted.

Comment: @Catija Though, meta sites already have a significantly reduced score threshold, compared to the main sites' -4.

Comment: @ChristianRau so meta has -4? did I read that wrong? I just added a screenshot of -8 post in my answer below.

Comment: @HackerKarma *"did I read that wrong?"* - Yes, you did. Main sites have -4. Meta's is lower (which actually is at -8, I think).

Comment: Heh, and look at me, shaking meta upside down, trying to find the post that tells me how to find -10-something questions using the new-nav. But it seems, there's no way of doing so *with using the new-nav*. :\

Answer (score 4):

You can bookmark this URL: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3aquestion

This is using the search mechanism to show all questions, sorted by last activity, bypassing any navigation system be it old or new.

Some points to consider:

- Being part of search, it's cached in a different way than ordinary question lists, so it might take a minute or two for new question to appear there.
- Being part of search, there is rate limiting involved i.e. if you reload this too much you will be blocked for a short while.

Comment: +1 for this bypass route. It also works with "newest" tab: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this happened before for a particular question which was downvoted heavily and later when I went to the main (newest) page again, it wasn't there. I <s>think</s> *believe* (read below) this falls under the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

I think it has something to do with the number of downvotes or offensive flags. The system may have some kinda algorithm behind the scene (a background process may be) which auto detects the post score and takes it out from the page as it's not worth for reading or a waste of time. Basically, it treats the post as a poor quality content which doesn't needed to be visible.

But, there is some kind threshold/limit for a post to be disappear. Here is the screenshot of a post that has -8 votes and I see it under the "newest" sort filter

> [image]

P.S.

As per [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/meta-sites-front-pages-should-not-hide-questions-with-very-low-scores/62769#62769) (ShadowWizard's comment pointed me to the answer), threshold limit is set to a global value of -8 for all metas.

So, basically it comes down to [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: True, score of -8 and lower cause the question to not be displayed in question lists.

Comment: Yes... but the "Newest" tab **used** to show them all, regardless of downvotes... pretty sure.

Comment: @Catija is correct, not just newest tab but any tab under `/questions` path (in the old navigation) as can be seen here:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl8Nh.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard so this change is for new-nav only? I see the -8 score on the "newest" page. Where to confirm the threshold

Comment: Yes this looks like one of many changes in the new navigation system

Comment: @ShadowWizard added screenshot for -8 post. But, where did u get the "score of -8 and lower cause the question to not be displayed..." is there a FAQ on this?

Comment: Yes, this is only for the new navigation and is caused by the fact that the new navigation does not make any distinction between the "Top Questions" frontpage and the normal "Questions" list anymore. Instead it employs the thresholding rules that were previously used for the frontpage only for all the question lists now.

Comment: @ChristianRau I guessed the same.  Now the only question left here is to find out the threshold/limit rule. As per ShadowWizard it's -8 and I can see that as I found the one (added screenshot to answer). I can see the -8 question under "newest" as well as "recently active" sort-filter.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117119/how-many-downvotes-to-push-an-active-question-off-the-active-list

Comment: @ShadowWizard thank you for the link... found the link to Jeff's post. Added note to answer

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the whole `new` tab has an (inclusive) -8 min score limit on child metas, and -4 on other sites by default, but can be overriden by a site setting (which is done on MSE, where -8 is specified explicitly, even though it's not a child meta).

I removed [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), because it is a regression as Andy pointed out in the comments to this answer. I'll bring it up for discussion with the team.

Comment: m0sa, could you please explain "which is the one that applies to MSE" which one? -8 or -4?

Comment: as I said, it's -4 since it's not a child meta, but a main site

Comment: But, OP's question is about MSE new tab, and I added a screenshot in my answer -8 post and which was shown under new tab. But, another negative vote i.e. -9 it got disappear. I'm little confused.

Comment: Without the new navigation, though, I can go to the newest tab and see ALL undeleted posts regardless of score. With the new navigation, those posts are just gone. I understand we don't want the low scores on the front page, but we do offer a way to see the questions away from the front page. That is no longer an option with the new navigation. A question with -8 on Meta means it is unpopular, but it is still important. For example, this [-155 scored question by Shog](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments).

Comment: If I wasn't around when such a question is posted, how do I see that even 10 minutes later? -155 on Meta is a HUGE number of votes. That question dropped quickly. How does someone that was at lunch, see it an hour later?

Comment: Or, the often quoted post about [maturity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126919/evaluating-the-risks-of-allowing-teen-moderators-on-the-se-network) - with a score of -90. Both of these questions provided answers that have become policy across the network. Not being able to see them and participate is bad. The option to see these questions now is to perform search voodoo or actively avoid the new navigation until it rolls out.

Comment: @HackerKarma ah, had to dig deeper, the code default is -4, but the config overrides it to -8... Answer is updated, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @m0sa 4 eyes better than 2 :) +1  Thanks for the update. Do I deserve an upvote for my answer from you? Also, for the fact, I did not DV you.

Comment: @Andy good point, need to talk through this as it really seems to be a regression vs. the old nav