# Why is "Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio" not on showing on top questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Ok clearly it is because it is getting so many down votes.

But can something be done so that is stays visible?

Had I not noticed it when I did, I might have missed it.

[Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/217279)

Comment: It is featured, so it will show up in the box on the right on all sites regardless of it's score. ---->

Comment: related [Show MSE posts authored by staff members on the homepage regardless of the vote count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332474/show-mse-posts-authored-by-staff-members-on-the-homepage-regardless-of-the-vote)

Comment: Banner blindness.