# What is the network policy regarding AI Generated content?

Tags: support, policy

Earlier this week, Stack Exchange released guidance to moderators on how to moderate AI Generated content. What does this guidance include?

Comment: Please upvote this. Downvote the answer all you want, but the question should remain on the front page.

Comment: @terdon: That'd mean that this would belong in a blog post rather than here on Meta Stack Exchange.  If we're voting on it, then we're tacitly discussing the quality of the policy, which is not a very good or agreeable policy.  [I have no intent on upvoting this question *just* because it's related to policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423720/1079354); it's up to the company to make the conversation inviting and the policy open for discussion/feedback.

Comment: @Makoto since this has been posted as a Q&A, we can vote on the A and Q separately. The Q is fine, had it not been posted by a member of staff it would have been upvoted. It's the answer we have issues with.

Comment: @terdon if there's a need for a feature to keep company posts at the top, the company can will it into existence. we don't need to use our votes to do that.

Comment: @terdon [relevant feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332474/383809)

Comment: I downvoted this question itself, simply because I'm angry at the way that the situation was handled, and because I disagree with everything that's happened so far. The post speaks for itself, and deserves votes based on this.

Comment: @terdon Yes, on meta it's okay to use voting for agreement/disagreement only for answers, not for questions, but people never really went with it. Many a fine question are downvoted because they didn't fit the mood. It's kind of the bad side of the community. However, I wished this question would give more context. Why did SO release guidance? Why is it released here now? What kind of input is expected from the community?

Comment: It feels to me like there's really mixed/ unfocused messaging going on here. The question title and body focus on "moderat[ing] AI Generated content", but the policy answer is primarily about user suspensions, and gives little to no concrete guidance on the aforementioned moderation of AI-generated _content_. Can you update the title & question to reflect the actual policy you've posted? It's genuinely really confusing to me what your main aim is here because the answer and question title seem so disconnected.

Comment: The current lock notice states "It is still accepting *answers*, comments and other interactions" (emphasis mine). If that is not the case, please change the lock type to the appropriate one to prevent any new answers being posted (I'm fairly sure I've seen this being used previously on some posts), rather than just deleting them all afterwards. If I'm mistaken and such an appropriate lock type doesn't exist, then please at least update the question text to explicitly state for members to not post any answers.

Comment: another weird thing: Your question post is written in a way that _nobody_ would have really asked that question. How would anyone but mods know that this happened earlier this week? And why would mods be wondering about something that presumably you would/should have made clear to them?

Comment: Side note: could the [tag:chatgpt] tag be added? It's locked so I can't, but... that is pretty directly connected to this post

Comment: Also, as this affects all sites on the network AFAIK, can you please feature this? It directly impacts the moderation of all sites, so it seems worthy of being featured (unless you're explicitly not featuring it to hide it, which would be a separate issue)

Comment: Please [discuss this policy here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389617/165261).

Comment: Echoing an earlier comment, why isn't this featured? Is it because it lacks the details necessary for meaningful discussion?

Comment: One more step to making Stack Overflow a first Q&A platform where answers are one hundred percent AI-generated.

Comment: I wonder what will happen first, humans leaving SE or SE replacing humans with AI that generates high-noise low-signal engagement.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Once people find out nobody's allowed to moderate AI content, Stack Overflow being all AI generated content with no people left active seems like an inevitability even with no further action from SO Inc.

Comment: If future content is heavily AI-generated, there will be no market for SE to license the content to AI generators for training... The _only_ way for SE content to be worth anything is for it to NOT be AI generated material.

Comment: @JonCuster Of course, and the sarcass here is that ChatGPT probably dig all sites including SO/SE, etc.. to write up the text. You allow to be indexed, and you get killed of it.. and too late to block crawler, there is already a ton of honey trap mirrors of the whole site online.

Comment: It says a lot that since this post went up, and the outcry it's had, that not a *single* staff member has made a comment on it; feels like the SO staff have light the match and thrown it on the pile to just watch the flames burn everything down. *Pyromaniacs...*

Comment: If I were staff, I would not feel safe hurling myself onto the pitchforks here. Whatever response they are planning, it's almost certainly not going to materialize as comments here. Just sayin'.

Comment: [discussion on reddit's r/programming](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/13w66j7/stack_overflow_and_stack_exchange_mods_no_longer/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) + [my comment there](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/13w66j7/comment/jmki7wx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: I have always been a bit leary of a company that makes a Billion dollars a year using free, (as in beer), labor. I have been stressed by the company's Luddite attitude toward ChatGPT and the suspension of contributors on suspicion alone. It is understandable that ChatGPT will likely make SE redundant and put it out of business, along with many other tech companies. It is refreshing to see SE or any other corporation morally take the risk of un-banning it. I picture the scene in Boris Karloff's Frankenstein and the crowd with pitchforks and torches.

Comment: This has been the trait of SE lately: disseminate a vague statement and abruptly impose on the community without paying heed to any active and well-meaning interaction. Solidarity for our mods!

Comment: @C.S.Cameron exactly.  I think that the crucial ingredients for a good AI policy for this site is 1) human-reviewed answers and 2) no AI questions.  Like 95% of the answer content on here could be outsourced to an LLM scraping know-how from tech blogs and documentation and tutorials and whatnot.  The question content, however, includes crucial information about "what sort of things do humans find difficult?" that just doesn't exist elsewhere on the internet in such a comprehensive fashion.  SE is THE seminal dataset on human ignorance.

Comment: @shadowwizardissadandangry cue [predicted management panic mode](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023/)

Answer (score 16):

The policy given to moderators in private, which was later [made public](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391626/):

> May 29, 2023
>
> ### Please stop use of GPT detectors for content moderation on Stack Exchange
>
> In light of significant research on the efficacy and flaws of GPT detectors, we’ve been studying the impacts of these detectors on Stack Exchange. And I’ve got some bad news to share.
>
> We made two major discoveries, which I’ll discuss in more detail in this post. To summarize, though, we have strong evidence that:
>
> 1. none of the GPT detectors work as advertised on Stack Exchange data and have egregious false detection rates on our platform, and
> 2. they are creating an alarming native language bias in suspensions on the platform.
>
> The tl;dr: ***We are now asking you to stop using GPT detectors to substantiate claims of GPT usage and to stop suspending due to AI-generated content in general***. Based on what we now know, we can’t admit GPT detectors’ results as reasonable evidence of GPT usage. To be clear: as of today, Philippe has instructed our team that GPT detectors will not be acceptable to establish reason-to-block. We will revisit this decision if evidence emerges that the issues with these tools have been resolved.
>
> #### GPT detectors do not work as advertised and produce unreliable results
>
> Based on significant and credible research that implies GPT detectors return excessive false positives, we conducted our own survey of GPT detector efficacy on Stack Exchange posts authored before ChatGPT’s November release. This survey concluded that GPT detectors misclassify 32% (+/- 6%) of non-GPT posts on Stack Exchange sites as having been written by GPT. This error rate is too high to be tenable for day-to-day use, and is certainly too high to establish cause for messaging or suspension.
>
> We also discovered that GPT detectors often disagree with each other as to whether a post is GPT created. This means that strategies relying on one of two detectors returning a positive result could lead to a baseline error rate of around 50% - and the incorrect detection rate gets *worse* the more detectors are added. In other words, 50% of posts detected as positive using an “either detector” strategy could be incorrectly classified as AI-written.
>
> However, we did not find a way to reduce the error rate far enough by combining GPT detector results. Relying on multiple GPT detectors returning positives at the same time will return an error rate in the range of 12% (+/- 7%). We expect that combining the results of additional detectors will not return more meaningful results. This is still too high for operational usage, particularly at the volume GPT messages and suspensions are issued on the platform today.
>
> If the situation changes and a GPT detector is released that meets our criteria for operational efficacy, we will revisit this policy change.
>
> #### GPT detectors are creating bias against non-native English speakers
>
> Even more alarmingly, recent research shows that GPT detectors exhibit overwhelming bias against non-native English speakers, and misclassify their writing as authored by GPT at a rate of ~45-80%. Available detectors are also unanimous in this misclassification around ~19% of the time. This risks unjustly targeting non-native English speakers on the platform, which comprise a significant majority of participants on some of our largest sites. (I would also hazard to say that non-native English speakers comprise the majority of participants on a majority of sites across the platform.)
>
> We conducted a survey of the site using our best available information, on the assumption that biases against non-native speakers (a feature we cannot analyze) would show up as biases for and against specific countries (a feature we can analyze).
>
> Our results *strongly* suggest that actual mod messages sent about GPT to users on the platform are significantly and inappropriately biased, likely driven by biases in the underlying tools used to flag GPT answers. To be clear, ***we do not believe that moderators are consciously acting with any sort of bias***, but that the tools that they are using for this task have that bias built into them.
>
> Regions of the world that appear to be unjustly targeted by GPT detectors in use on our platform include southeast Asia, the Middle East, and most of Africa. Regions of the world unjustly benefited by GPT detectors include North America, Europe, and Oceania.
>
> The effect sizes are not small. For example, Pakistan receives 3.6x more suspensions for GPT usage than their baseline participation rates should imply. Bangladesh receives 2.7x more suspensions than the base participation rate justifies. India receives 1.75x more suspensions. On the other hand, the United States receives 0.6x the suspension rate, alongside Sweden, Great Britain, and Australia. While we unfortunately can’t share the raw data from our conclusions, we hope that these data points help to convince you that our alarm is justified.
>
> Bear in mind that some of the reason we *suspect* GPT detectors create this bias is because they are detecting patterns in language that non-native speakers rely on. *Therefore we also cannot accept similarities between the structure of a user’s answers alone as an indicator of GPT usage.*
>
> #### Only self-admission, freely given, can count as evidence of GPT usage on the platform
>
> In light of the above, there are no tools currently available (at least so far as we are aware) that can identify GPT usage successfully. Therefore, the scope of admissible evidence for establishing GPT usage is, in the current state of things, very thin.
>
> - GPT detectors cannot be counted as evidence for the reasons above.
> - User behavior, such as answer timing, could be *correlated with* GPT usage, but a hunch alone does not a suspension make. Instead, this signal has to be taken as a prompt to review the objective quality of the user’s contributions.
> - You may consider things that have *obviously* been copy pasted from ChatGPT such as literally mentioning the knowledge cutoff date from ChatGPT or phrases that include things like "If this didn't help, you can use a forum like Stack Overflow and ask for help there" to be self-admission and AI generated.
>
> **Therefore, the only admissible evidence we can currently permit for GPT usage is self-admission by the author of the posts, freely given.** Please note that “freely given” is important here: please do not, under any circumstances, try to trick users into admitting GPT usage, lure them into saying it, or otherwise coerce a response. Even a user saying they have used GPT *in general* may not count unless they specifically say they have used it *here*, or for *this contribution*.
>
> As a final reminder, suspensions should only be issued for **real behavior, actually known to be malfeasance**. We just can’t endorse kicking users off the platform on the basis of hunches, intuitions, guesses, or untested/untestable heuristics.
>
> ---
>
> We are aware that this leaves the state of GPT enforcement on the site in pretty rough shape. The silver lining is that these tools don’t really seem to have been working as designed anyway.
>
> Here are the key points we’d like you to take away from this post:
>
> - We are now requiring you to *ignore and/or decline reports* using online GPT detectors or intuition as their basis. Remember that users have honed their instincts as to what a GPT contribution ‘sounds’ like based on input and signals from GPT detectors that are now known to be bad.
> - Do not direct users to GPT detectors or encourage them to act on their results in any way. Users, as well as moderators, should not be using these tools to determine post and user outcomes.
> - The only admissible evidence for GPT usage is self-admission; however, you should not solicit self-admission from users.
> - **Remember that mod messages and suspensions are for real, verifiable malfeasance only**, and should not be enacted on the basis of hunches, guesses, intuition, or unvetted heuristics.
> - Effective immediately, Philippe has revoked the temporary policy change allowing moderators to jump to 30 day suspensions for GPT usage. In light of the current evidence, we simply do not trust that the tooling exists to support suspensions with the required degree of confidence. Although this policy was only formally enacted on Stack Overflow, any network sites that have informally been working under such a policy should also now consider that policy overturned, and should no longer be acting on it.
>
> As far as the existing suspensions go, we will let active suspensions that were issued for a time period of less than 90 days expire organically. We’ll only review these suspensions if users contact us. For suspensions that were issued for a time period of 90 days or greater, we’ll manually review these to determine if they can be removed (they’re not just flooding bad content, for example).
>
> #### Low quality content
>
> You may still naturally deal with content abuse in ways we always have: if someone is posting a flood of poor quality content, **suspend them for low quality content**. Just don’t make it about GPT or AI generated content - make it about the quality being poor on a repeated basis. This includes things like repeated answers that don't address the question.
>
> If someone is posting a flood of content to promote their tool/site/blog, use the astroturfing policy we have.
>
> One final note: The amount of content deleted for GPT usage is truly astounding across the network. While we don’t doubt users have been using GPT and other language models to post answers, if you’ve been using GPT detectors to mark individual answers for deletion, we’d ask you to consider carefully whether any such content needs undeleting. Keep in mind, false positives are dramatically more likely for authentic writing by users who do not natively speak English, and may run as high as 80% for some detectors; in these cases, users may not deserve to have their content removed. Additionally, it remains possible that a false positive on one answer means false positives on other answers by that user are more likely to occur.
>
> If you have questions, let us know in the answers below and Philippe is also willing to schedule a meeting in the TL if needed to discuss it further.

Comment: should this also be locked to prevent editing? (the source post is locked)

Comment: @starball I'll flag it and request to add the lock. P.S. The title of the policy given to mods was this: "Please stop use of GPT detectors for content moderation on Stack Exchange" (according to [Laurel's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1309300)).

Answer (score -439):

We recently performed a set of analyses on the current approach to AI-generated content moderation. The conclusions of these analyses strongly indicate to us that AI-generated content is not being properly identified across the network, and that the potential for false-positives is very high. Through no fault of moderators' own, we also suspect that there have been biases for or against residents of specific countries as a potential result of the heuristics being applied to these posts. Finally, internal evidence strongly suggests that the overapplication of suspensions for AI-generated content may be turning away a large number of legitimate contributors to the site.

In order to help mitigate the issue, we've asked moderators to apply a very strict standard of evidence to determining whether a post is AI-authored when deciding to suspend a user. This standard of evidence excludes the use of moderators' best guesses based on users' writing styles and behavioral indicators, because we could not validate that these indicators are actually successfully identifying AI-generated posts when they are written. This standard would exclude most suspensions issued to date.

We've also identified that current GPT detectors have an unacceptably high false positive rate for content on our network and should not be regarded as reliable indicators of GPT authorship. While these aren't the sole tools that moderators rely upon to identify AI-generated content, some of the heuristics used have been developed with their assistance.

We've reminded moderators that suspensions (and typically mod messages as well) are for real, verifiable malfeasance only, and should not be enacted on the basis of hunches, guesses, intuition, or unverified heuristics. Therefore, we are not confident that either GPT detectors or best-guess heuristics can be used to definitively identify suspicious content for the purposes of suspension.

As always, moderators who identify that a user has a problematic pattern of low-quality posts should continue to act on such users as they otherwise would. Indicators moderators currently use to determine that a post was authored with the help of AI can in some cases form a reliable set of indicators that the content quality may be poor, and moderators should feel free to review posts as such. If someone is repeatedly contributing low-quality content, we already have policies in place to help handle it, including a suspension reason that can, in those cases, be used.

Comment: This post does not match the guidance given to moderators.

Comment: Can we please have concrete numbers for the _"unacceptably high false positive rate"_ from your research?

Comment: Among other problems, this post needs a clear statement of what the guidance is, i.e. "AI-generated posts are allowed as long as they meet other post quidelines."

Comment: @E_net4 We mods didn't even get them. That said, they ran it on old questions, proving that there's a bias in the detectors (which there are independent studies already confirming). However, they've never run any actual checks to prove that there is a false positive rate _in suspensions_, as most suspensions do not rely only on the output of GPT detectors. They've been bashed for this internally, and have so far ignored that feedback

Comment: "In order to help mitigate the issue, we've asked moderators to apply a very strict standard of evidence to determining whether a post is AI-authored when deciding to suspend a user." The guidance I have received is: "We are now asking you to stop [...] suspending due to AI-generated content in general". How do I reconcile these two statements?

Comment: "*We've reminded moderators that [...]Therefore, we are not confident that either GPT detectors or best-guess heuristics can be used to definitively identify suspicious content for the purposes of suspension.*" This is exactly why SO had the policy of ChatGPT being banned... because one _can't rely on anything about it being accurate_. This is exactly the danger of "AI" and this policy seems counterintuitive because it seems to invite _more_ "AI" into the site instead of less.

Comment: (Cont'd) The policy should reflect a restriction in _suspensions by moderators_, but should **not** attempt to affect the acceptability of AI or suspected AI authored content _in posts_. That is the critical failing of this decision IMHO.

Comment: so, effectively, the new approach to handling AI generated content is to not?

Comment: @KevinB Correct. SE no longer cares about AI content polluting the site, because their stats are dropping thanks to CGPT being an active competitor

Comment: We protested this update vehemently and you went ahead with it anyway. Apparently it's not clear to the team how much this will negatively impact the quality of the network. If there's anything we can do to help you see the light, please say so.

Comment: @Andy (and Philippe), we were not "asked", we were "required". I don't know why Philippe is suddenly turning into a spin doctor here, and I am guessing this isn't his choice, but let's be very clear: we were not _asked_, we were _required_ and told what to do. That is a very significant difference.

Comment: For everyone else equally infuriated by this decision, [strike discussions](https://discord.gg/FCWJXZM) have started up.

Comment: We moderators have been assured that there are distressing "indicators" that our handling of suspensions has been suboptimal. This answer would be substantially improved with concrete exposition of those indicators and how they are unfair to community members or harm Stack Overflow's business interests.

Comment: Strange answer, I guess lets just escalade ChatGPT's flag to CM.  The ultimate goal is, why SE dont create a ChatGPT detection tool for mod to use and base their decision off it.

Comment: "Finally, internal evidence strongly suggests that the overapplication of suspensions for AI-generated content may be turning away a large number of legitimate contributors to the site." It is not legitimate to pollute these sites with AI generated garbage.

Comment: You seem to be completely oblivious of how we actually moderate AI content. **I suggest you actually come talk to us, and the moderators, and look into the chat rooms we use for this curation**, to understand that we _are_ reasonable in our moderation efforts, and we don't just throw around accusations and suspensions without being on steady ground.

Comment: I have yet to see you actually interact with us over this, and draw any sort of explanation and understanding from us at all. This is a huge insult.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship Also worth noting that they've gotten mountains of feedback pointing out all of this, and have ignored all of it. They know it isn't how we operate, they've been told that AI content isn't reliable, but it doesn't matter to them anymore. They've provided some surface-level stats internally, but none showing that the FP rate exists in suspensions, nor any stats to back up any of their other internal claims

Comment: @yagmoth555 It is mathematically and logically impossible for such a tool to exist, and work. It is computer-sciencely impossible to have an infallible detection algorithm with fewer than (the order of) eight-bytes-compressed minimal text units, since otherwise you could run it backwards and, by brute force, produce undetectable automated text. At this point I wouldn't completely put it _past_ Stack Exchange to do something like you propose, but that'd be worse than even this policy.

Comment: So ChatGPT is still banned but nobody gets suspended anymore for it? That would kind of defeat the ban. See also: [How can we determine whether an answer used ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421880/how-can-we-determine-whether-an-answer-used-chatgpt)

Comment: "biases for or against residents of specific countries" I have difficulties understanding this. I can only identify if somebody speaks English as mother language or not and even that not with high confidence. AI generated content typically has top grammar and style. If anything the false positive rate might be higher for really well formulated content, but then don't we all strive for this?

Comment: @Trilarion that really confsed me too, but see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.02819.pdf. A very limited study, on data (TOEFL essays all written by people using the same course, and speaking the same mother tongue) that are fundamentally different to SE content, so I don't know how relevant it is here, but that's an example of how detectors under certain circumstances may indeed be biased.

Comment: Many one final comment, the false error rate may be controllable. One might be able to use a higher confidence threshold in these scanners and arrive at a lower, acceptable false positive suspension rate. Alternatively, wait a bit and use the scanner on multiple answers from the same account and use an aggregate score. That should have a lower error rate.

Comment: The whole premise is flawed because it starts from "regular users might use biased AI detectors" and the conclusion is "mods can't be trusted to judge from many kinds of signals whether a post is AI-written" which is the kind of fallacy that's hard to take as an honest mistake. Painting this all with "in the name of inclusivity" just drives it further home how cynical this all is. Not sure it's worth arguing about the face value of the "arguments" made by the company (for want of a better word).

Comment: this seems to substantially limit means to control quality of the posted content. Was company planning to compensate this somehow?

Comment: This post is manipulative. You have been told time and time again how you are wrong. Moderators have been very clear in the fact that you say one thing behind locked doors, and another in public. As such, I consider this post offensive.

Comment: 99% of moderation is performed by regular users like me, but this post provides zero guidance for regular users like me. You haven’t even answered your own question, which was “What does this guidance include?”

Comment: “AI detectors might be xenophobic, so we’ve decided to allow AI content.”

Comment: What would make sense as an alternative would be for the company to devise a _better_ process for moderators to handle AI content, not a worse one. Off the cuff, some quick ideas; require two mods to agree on the verdict, or (gasp) have the company invest in hiring and training staff to handle these posts separately from the regular mod flow. This obviously only addresses the acute problem, but would show a way forward for the longer term.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine "..That said, they ran it on old questions.." That's a reasonable thing to do. I proposed to do that already [in December 2022](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422063/1536976). However not telling about the exact results is kind of not inspiring confidence. And there doesn't seem to be enough confidence in the company left. However, everyone else could do that same thing, i.e. run scanners on content created before 2022.

Comment: The communities decided in most places "we don't want AI content" and you say "We allow it..." - that still means the communities **don't want it**

Comment: @ThomasMarkov moderators have not received any more guidance than this. In both cases it is just a "don't do this" message.

Comment: Is a user who has never or hardly ever used capitalization and punctuation, has through the months or years of their activity written answers full of typos and "try this" in lieu of explanations of their solutions, and suddenly learned to write with perfect grammar and spelling, full-sentenced, plausible-sounding but conceptually entirely wrong answers not evidence enough? If not, then what is?

Comment: @CodeCaster Last week or so I came across an answer with an initial version that was sloppy in style and had a lot of grammar mistakes, and in an edit it was converted to the signature chatgpt style complete with needless recap paragraph at the end. It was clearly done by chatgpt. _But_ the technical part of the answer was unchanged. While the final state was technically written by chatgpt, I think this was fine in the spirit of the gpt ban: the issue is when gpt writes the technical part. So no, style and AI detection is not enough. But flat out banning AI banning is the wrong conclusion.

Comment: Although your comment includes "conceptually entirely wrong" (may have been added as an edit?), in which case I agree. And these are exactly the kinds of circumstances our mods can use and have been using.

Comment: @Andras AI to fix your writing style has existed for decades; it's called spell check.

Comment: @IanCampbell SE Inc.'s business "model" has been built on "infinite growth promised to investors", and disallowing AI-generated crap and removing users who spam it is a clear and obvious threat to that "model".

Comment: It looks to me like they see bad traffic numbers in their future and they’re positioning mods as meatshields to buy time. Also consider they may be having conversations like “Could we use AI to mod SO?”  You’re all right to be angry.

Comment: A bias in flags for certain countries/regions is not specificaly bound to AI-related flags. Removing those flag won't solve the bias for other flags.

Comment: Do you have examples of "legitimate users" who were driven away by being wrongly suspended for ChatGPT content? The ChatGPT content I've seen hasn't exactly been stellar quality. For example, I got a ChatGPT answer on one of my questions that didn't answer the question in the least.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні The case you suggest (using GPT to edit an existing answer) has been discussed in the past.  My understanding is that the consensus among moderators is that this is fine, as long as the user discloses this in their answer (GPT's terms of service require attribution).

Comment: "_the potential for false-positives is very high._" How do you know that ?

Comment: *Finally, internal evidence strongly suggests that the overap...* ... *Through no fault of moderators' own, we also suspect that...* So, it's ok for you to  make decisions based on **suspicions** and **suggestions**, but moderators and users can't?

Comment: Be careful ! After ChatGPT generated posts get into SE, copyright lawsuits against SO/SE could happen.

Comment: I would like to reiterate: has SE identified concrete cases where you know for a fact that someone was actually wrongfully suspended, or do you merely think that it's probably happening based on other evidence? How do you know how frequently it's happening (or even *whether* it's happening) unless you yourselves have a way to reliably identify whether content was generated by AI? Also, how does the number of false suspensions balance against the number of correct suspensions? If 99.95% of the suspensions were warranted, do we need a policy change for the 0.05%?

Comment: @EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine: I think there was an [MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest) where someone claimed that (or wanted an explanation). But I can't locate it right now. It was within the last one or two months.

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be to analyze what motivates people to post AI-generated answers in the first place. Are they doing it out of a genuine but misguided desire to help? Are they just doing it for rep points? Is there a way to remove the motivation or disincentivize the act of posting AI-generated answers?

Comment: "Through no fault of moderators' own, we also suspect that there have been biases for or against residents of specific countries as a potential result of the heuristics being applied to these posts." When "residents of specific countries" habitually write in poor or heavily dialectic English, then suddenly start showing up with Grammarly-perfect US-high-school-textbook prose - then yes, it will be more noticeable than if people who are already native English speakers start using ChatGPT. *But rather than come up with something so obvious, you'd rather insinuate that we're all racist.* Classy.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine no, they haven't. Staff have even told us this in the Teacher's Lounge. What they have is a disproportionally high rate of suspension, but no evidence whatsoever that these were also disproportionally wrongly issued, the best they can point to is that many more people have complained about AI-related suspensions than about any other type of suspension. In fairness, it would be hard to get proof of wrong suspensions, we can know they're right if the user apologizes, but if they say nothing or claim they're innocent, how can you know the truth?

Comment: "We've reminded moderators that suspensions (and typically mod messages as well) are for real, verifiable malfeasance only, and should not be enacted on the basis of hunches, guesses, intuition, or unverified heuristics."  Is there any statistics over how many users that have been incorrectly accused of posting AI-generated content and appealed to have their ban lifted? In relation to how many such AI-generated posts that were deleted in total. As in: is this an actual problem or an imagined one?

Comment: @terdon I am a frequent visitor of Charcoal HQ chat room. In the past 5 months or so, I have seen numerous AI-generated posts with spam links on many SE sites. I am willing to bet those spammers will never apologize or say anything or claim they're innocent,. They just keep doing it.

Comment: @Lundin It seems like, the Physics.SE moderators have just posted a statement https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14438/physics-se-remains-a-site-by-humans-for-humans saying that on their site they've issued 17 warnings for suspected AI-generated content since December and received no replies or objections from the users who posted them, so that's one data point.

Comment: @Nobody precisely my point: if the user accepts the accusation and apologizes, that tells us the suspension was issued fairly. But I don't know how to ascertain that a suspension was issued unfairly: either the user says nothing or they complain, but just because they complain doesn't mean they are telling the truth. All of this is why we are so angry at SE because they are pretending to be acting on data, but the data they have cannot be used to demonstrate a high rate of wrong suspensions.

Comment: @terdon Agree. Our problem is how to wake up SO/SE staff ?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel *insinuate*? That's pretty blatantly stated :) One of the reasons I did not expect to find in the public "explanation", but here we again.

Comment: One day, AI will give better answers than the wisest of people on whole SE, or even on the planet. But that day has not just come yet. But I think allowing AI written answers with maybe a TAG of AI on it, would be a good idea. The basic motive of the website (if it is) is to help people around the world when they need!! Reputation on the website and other things are secondary and always should be.

Comment: “The conclusions of these analyses strongly indicate to us that AI-generated content is not being properly identified across the network, and that the potential for false-positives is very high.” - Complete hogwash, in every single case of reporting AI generated content, I am 100% confident it not only was complete trash it also was generated by an AI. This new policy is beyond frustrating, users who post AI garbage (all AI generated content is complete trash), don’t deserve to be allowed to submit contributions. **Once again SE ignores the community.**

Comment: @A.B. To clarify, we've received no replies that were complaints. We've received two replies that were apologies.

Comment: @Nobody "*I am willing to bet those spammers will never apologize or say anything or claim they're innocent,.*" well, spammers is really a different case. Their accounts are usually nuked, thus the system automatically imposed the suspension without a mod message, and thus no way to apologize even if they wanted. Unless they use "contact us" to the CM!

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. The point is : are they included in the statistics? 50 FPs among 200 suspended accounts is 25%. But, if there were 300 AI-generated texts nuked because they were spams, were they counted as FP or TP ? Even if counted as TP, what was the reason? spam or R/A or AI-generated? You are mod on 2 sites. You know more than I do.

Comment: @Nobody well, we don't know either. The statistics have never been released even to the mods, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. - They won’t be. I fully expect a partnership to be announced between SE and OpenAI any day, would explain this new policy and situations, where the content isn’t allowed but won’t actually be deleted.

Comment: I don't think the "statistics" is convincing anyone here. In fact, the implication that the audience here will fall for it is rather insulting. I'd much rather SE be honest and say: "we think business is going to hell with this moderation policy, so stop".

Comment: It seems fairly clear that you're doing this because you *want* the AI content, but why do you want that? In a few years LLMs will be much improved and even more widely available, but you'll still be stuck with all the old low-quality answers from old 2023-vintage models. There's no way that's going to be good for you in the long term. (And it's hard to see much short-term benefit to it either.)

Comment: SE's biggest asset is that it has a very high quality source of training material for AI. I would expect that a key long term goal of SE is to build its _own_ LLMs to provide a (clearly demarcated!) AI assistant. To do this, _SE content must always exceed the quality of the best AI content_. Accepting AI-generated content directly conflicts with such an aspiration: **garbage in, garbage out.**

Comment: @ShikharChamoli I have flagged quite a few ChatGPT written posts in the SO java tag, and they have not been helpful answers. They are either wrong or misunderstand the question. People who want to use ChatGPT to get answers can use it directly, if they like. Its output doesn't belong here. It doesn't help anybody.

Comment: ChatGPT is noise, not signal.  The value proposition of SE/SO is a very high, signal to noise ratio. The Moderation on SO and SE is done here by people **who are paid zero dollars per hour**, and **zero dollars per word**.  This policy might be viable if you were actually paying your moderators - community and diamond_ money to do their work. A style of *Shut up and color since I pay you* works that way.  You need to stop taking your volunteers for granted.  This same Tone deaf nonsense cropped up during the Monicamoderationthing.

Comment: I totally support you Phillipe, please don't let a few handful of people ruin the experience of a majority contributors to the site who are legitimate as you described them.

Comment: The biases are probably because more people from those geographic areas are using AI.

Comment: @Nobody *"the potential for false-positives is very high." How do you know that ?* Whenever I see AI generated content on the internet I usually ask the same question. Are we sure these policies weren't written by AI?

Comment: @Nobody I thought I was agreeing with your comment? One of the most notable characteristics of AI that I've seen is unverified claims presented in a confident manner. I was poking fun at that fact and half jokingly accusing SO of using AI to set moderation policies and generate public comments.

Comment: @mchid Sorry for the misunderstanding. Right now, I am more concerned about the recent spam attacks. If it goes on like this, we become the heaven for the spammers. In the past 2 hours, I raised 15 spam flags on Academia.SE. We'll have no space to ask/answer questions. The new users will walk away once they see those spams. I don't think this is what SE, Inc. wants.

Comment: In other words, the longer the strike is, the less the new users will stay. It's not AI issue anymore. SE, Inc. will have to find ways to kill spams, either auto delete or manual delete. Both will cost money. How much SE is willing to spend and how long will SE survive ?

Comment: Well, my personal consequence is retracting from SE, stopping any active contribution to any sub-site, see my profile. This will be my last comment for as long as the ban of LLM-generated content remains suspended.

Comment: This is an old policy - this triggered a strike, and has since been superseded [this post should get you caught up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an)