# Add # next to each answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

I would like to suggest adding the answer number (#) to each answer on a page. This makes it easier to know which answer you are at when scrolling down a list of many and long answers.

For instance, I was reading through the answers of this post: [GPT on the platform: Data, actions, and outcomes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes)

and I got lost as to which answer I was at and how many are remaining.

Comment: What would the numbering be based on? When an answer receives a vote or two, would it exchange numbers with the answer above it - that could happen while you're reading, so how would it help?

Comment: It should be based on the order they appear

Comment: @machine_1 this can be different between reloads, so it is likely to cause even more confusion ("look at answer #3, it says xyz" "no it doesn't, it says abc!")

Comment: @Esther The numbering isn't to refer an answer to someone in this context. It's just for keeping track of what have you read per session. I know the answer order may change after a reload.

Comment: @machine_1 how many questions do you think would be posted to meta about numbers not matching across reloads/different computers? it would be very confusing to most users.

Comment: Small tips: perhaps you might consider using an answer sorting order that is more determinable: date created?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add this using a userstyle like the following:

```css
div.answer {
    counter-increment: answer;
}

div.answercell::before {
    content: "Answer " counter(answer);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:2em;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

This will result in posts like:

[image]

[image]