# If I answer my own question, will it decrease its visibility thus reduce the chance of other people giving a better answer?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, self-answer

I asked a question, and I already have a nonperfect answer.

I want to submit my nonperfect answer. This way, if other people have the same solution as mine, they don't need to bother typing it again.

But I still hope a perfect answer will appear, and I fear that answering my own question will reduce the chance of that happening by reducing the visibility.

Comment: Some people might skip past the question if it has an answer, yes, people do weird things.

Comment: How about posting the question and waiting a day or two to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: Why not edit the question with that answer as something you tried, then give criteria for why it's not optimal. As I understand it, the edit bumps the thing. But beware of unnecessary edits as they attract attention for abuse of the system.

Comment: Might also depend on the network. On SO posting a working solution in the question and asking for a "better" one might not be well received. you'd need to be pretty specific about what things you don't want in the existing solution and why.

Comment: if it's a non perfect answer you could just edit it into the question and ask for improvements. I don't think it necessarily reduces visibility, but your question probably won't show up in the unanswered tab in the site's front page

Comment: Adding an answer does not by itself "decrease visibility" other than for users who deliberately skip or filter out questions with answers. The system itself does not distinguish between self-answers and other answers, or default to demoting answered questions (other than in specific views for users who prefer to view unanswered questions).

Comment: There's always Cunningham's law ""The best way to get the right answer on the Internet is not to ask a question; it's to post the wrong answer."." That said, the wrong answer needs to be backed up by something. Non perfect is fine, people will fix it for you

Comment: Yes, people count on the fasted gun in the west effect, and are less likely to answer your question, unless your answer is so contentious that it will attract several people who will want to "edit" it.

Comment: [FGITW reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533).

Comment: (And ChatGPT-induced FGITW [may be the explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned/425098#425098) for the [answerers crash on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes/389960#389960).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the technical side, there is nothing implemented that would change the visibility of the question in any meaningful way. All that happens is that the number of answers is displayed as 1 instead of 0, in small text. It does not affect the sorting of questions. It affects explicit queries based on the number of answers, but not many people do that. An *accepted* answer affects the highlighting in the main listing of questions; but you don't have to accept your own answer (and shouldn't if it's partial... and can't for at least two days anyway).

There is not really any telling what will happen on the social side. Some people are actively interested in unanswered questions, because they want to be first. (There are reasons someone might *want* not to attract the attention of those users.) Some people are actively interested in answered questions, because they want to review, correct, nitpick etc. answers for a variety reasons (ranging from entirely altruistic to entirely egotistical).

If you have a partial answer, generally it's better from a building-the-site-library perspective to share what you have rather than keeping it to yourself. Please try to write it in a way that clearly marks the limitations (i.e. *why* it only qualifies as a partial answer, in your view). However, please also try to avoid writing as if you were on a discussion forum ("I have something that sort of works, it's what I'm going with for now... I would greatly appreciate any enhancements..." etc. etc.; i.e., writing about *you* rather than *the problem being solved*) - [because you aren't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950).