# What percentage of users mod-warned (no suspension) for posting AI-generated answers have gone on to write legitimate answers?

Tags: support, rules, moderator-messages, chatgpt

Put differently, what percentage of users who post AI-generated answers have demonstrated motivation to contribute content without violating site-specific AI-generated content policies or [the rules for referencing material written by others](/help/referencing)?

The reason I have ruled out user who have gotten suspensions for policy/rule violations when posting AI-generated content from the population of this query is because I want to rule out cases where a suspension has potentially discouraged such a user from further contributing (legitimately), which is [something the company has expressed concern about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389928/997587). It'd also be interesting to flip this criteria to try to get some approximate insight on that, but that can be for another question post.

I recognize that it's hard practically to get data on this since many flags for potential policy/rule violations may still be pending (such as they are on Stack Overflow right now, with roughly 4k pending). So I think users who have been mod-warned and have posts created after their mod warning that have pending flags with text related to AI-generated content policies should be removed from the query population.

It would be interesting to see views of the data with an added dimension, such as

- number of legitimate answer posts before being warned for policy/rule-violating answer posts, account age, etc. Since, for example, I imagine that a user who has posted many legitimate answers and experimented with posting AI-generated answers briefly would be more likely to continue to contribute legitimately compared to someone with no prior answer contributions.
- how long ago the warning happened. Presumably more time elapsed has positive correlation to "likelihood" of making a legitimate contribution.

I'm going through my saves lists of ChatGPT things and looking at deleted answers and their authors, and pretty much all the newer accounts I've seen with no prior answering activity have just gone silent. I've also seen a few users who continue to post things that meet proposed heuristics for detecting AI-generated content, but seem to be potentially putting more effort info obfuscation.

I can't query this info myself. I think staff support would be needed to do these queries.

Comment: "user who has posted many legitimate answers and experimented with posting AI-generated answers" - IMO, those are rarely "caught" as they won't just copy and paste. So, hard to tell.

Comment: Is this specifically about the mod message? Because on my sites, I just either: 1) put the "citation needed" post notice, or 2) post a comment asking for the source/reference, but never mod-message them.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. do you only do that when you're confident that the post is AI-generated (instead of something like "note: if this is AI-generated, ...")? If you only do it when you're confident, then yes, I also want that to be included. For the sake of the "purity" of the data, I'd prefer if only cases that match against approved heuristics are included, but I welcome answers from mods about cases that don't match against currently approved heuristics as long as it's clearly stated as being that.

Comment: None. No one reforms. Most give up entirely (say, after suspension and/or after their "carefully crafted" plagiarised answers have been wiped out), but [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11845013/md-al-amin) continue unabated as if nothing had happened, putting in the extra work to avoid detection (though there is still a very clear difference in writing style before and after December 2022 (it is *very* safe to assume no one learns anything or improve (that is extremely rare))). The name of the game is minimum effort, after all.