# When does the SE "senior leadership" plan to re-enable the uploads of the data dump to Archive.org?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I read this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389582/178179) written by [AMtwo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/314146/amtwo):

> The job that uploads the data dump to Archive.org was disabled on 28 March, and marked to not be re-enabled without approval of senior leadership.

This is a huge change, as it means SE is now trying to keep SE user data stuck within SE.

When does the SE "senior leadership" plan to re-enable the uploads of the data dump to Archive.org?

Comment: why would you expect they plan to re-enable them?

Comment: @MadScientist-onstrike I have no expectations, never is  a valid answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [June 2023 Data Dump is missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389922/june-2023-data-dump-is-missing) (note there's now a staff answer).

Comment: Didn't downvote but I would say that the previous discussion was still pretty new (only 2 days old) and it would be better for "senior leadership" to reply to that discussion since it already had a `status-review` tag (if you were expecting them to respond). I would have waited at least a week.

Comment: @CaveJohnson I wanted a question asking clearly for the upload date

Comment: See also [What is the current (June 2023) status of the data dumps and the company’s commitment to them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390201/what-is-the-current-june-2023-status-of-the-data-dumps-and-the-company-s-commi) (by SE staff, although that question was closed, so that answer may end up getting moved elsewhere)