# What is the current (June 2023) status of the data dumps and the company’s commitment to them?

Tags: support, data-dump, announcements

What is the current (June 2023) status of the data dumps, the API, and the Data Explorer?  Will the company continue to provide them going forward?

Comment: This is a straight duplicate: [June 2023 Data Dump is missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389922/205798). Consider just merging, or getting your answer to be picked (it warrants it now that there's more info!)

Comment: As one of the close voters: while it is appreciated that the company reversed course on data dumps, we are currently at a point where the company has severely broken community trust, so let's go by the book: we close as duplicates based on the applicability of answers. Historically, staff had leeway for that, but in light of recent events, this (posting an exact duplicate as a self Q&A) just looks like an attempt to spin public perception (since you don't even link to the original post). I suggest deleting the answer and rewriting the question to have *detailed* info on the matter.

Comment: For more information on closed questions, see your help article, [What does it mean if a question is “closed”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) In particular, your question was closed as a duplicate: this is okay! Duplicates help users find the answers they are looking for. However, as you have self-answered this question, we would encourage you to instead provide your answer on the linked duplicate, so that it can be seen on the canonical question about this topic. Thanks for participating in meta!

Comment: @ThomasMarkovisonStrike Well, they already provided an answer there before posting this, so is your encouragement to provide a second duplicate answer there? ;)

Comment: Closing such an official announcement (that gives us one of the things we have been asking for) as a duplicate makes literally no sense.

Comment: @wimi creating a new question that is an exact duplicate and does not address the concerns raised in the previous question makes less sense imo.

Comment: @wimi because this is not an announcement. It is an exact duplicate repost of what Philippe already provided on the original question, made in a style (self Q&A) that goes contrary to how staff announcements are made. Don't take my word for it: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389359), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389123), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389060), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388400). I stand by my close vote and encourage others to not VTR or reclose if it gets reopened *until the OP either makes it not an exact duplicate*.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine this format is still **much** better than the announcement being the fourth answer to a question asked one week ago by a regular user. I would never have seen the announcement there. And it is just by chance that I clicked on this question when it had -6 and was marked as a duplicate of a post that has been there for a week. The community should not try to hide official announcements that give us part of what we asked for. That looks like a strategy to keep users uninformed and biased against SE.